# Mapping a Component inside a Component Collection

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to map a value object collection where these contain other value objects but am getting the below exception.

**nHibernate Exception:**

```
 ----> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException : Could not find a getter for property '_timeAtAddress' in class 'CustomerAddress'
```

**Domain:**

```
public class CustomerAddress
{
    private TimePeriod _timeAtAddress;

    protected CustomerAddress() { }

    public CustomerAddress(TimePeriod timeAtAddress)
    {
        _timeAtAddress = timeAtAddress;
    }

    public TimePeriod TimeAtAddress { get { return _timeAtAddress; } }
}

public class TimePeriod
{
    private readonly int _months;
    private readonly int _years;

    protected TimePeriod() { }

    public TimePeriod(int months, int years)
    {
        _months = months;
        _years = years;
    }

    public int Months { get { return _months; } }
    public int Years { get { return _years; } }
}
```

**nHibernate Mapping:**

```
contact.HasMany<CustomerAddress>(Reveal.Member<Contact>("_customerAddresses"))
    .Schema(...)
    .Table(...)
    .KeyColumn(...)
    .AsBag()
    .Not.LazyLoad()
    .Component(address =>
    {
        .
        .
        .

        address.Component(Reveal.Member<CustomerAddress, TimePeriod>("_timeAtAddress"), timeAtAddress =>
        {
            timeAtAddress.Map(Reveal.Member<TimePeriod>("_years")).Column("TIME_YEARS");
            timeAtAddress.Map(Reveal.Member<TimePeriod>("_months")).Column("TIME_MONTHS");
        });
    });
```

Had a quick look at Access but can't seem to figure out where to set that up for components. Can you help?

Comment: Why are you adding the component in the HasMany relation? Have you tried only call a reference to a Address?

Comment: Not sure if I follow, what would you change there?

Comment: Im asuming you don't need to use the `Component` method in the `HasMany` relation, just guessing you should add only the address reference. Just give it a try.

Comment: Wouldn't that force the addresses to be mapped as proper entities instead of value objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I managed to move forward (using the private field) was to set a global Access.Field convention.

`.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Customer>()
                                      .Conventions.Add(DefaultAccess.Field()))`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than configuring FluentNHibernate to set the private field, shouldn't you be telling it to use the constructor argument?

My gut feeling is that the mistake is here:

```
address.Component(Reveal.Member<CustomerAddress, TimePeriod>("_timeAtAddress")
```

Where you're telling it to use the field `_timeAtAddress`.

Comment: Could you show a mapping example using the ctor please?